# How can I control a PrimeNG range slider?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to modify the values of a Primeng slider through two inputs. When the slider is not a range, it works fine, and I can control the slider from the input. However, when it comes to a range slider, it stops working, and I'm unable to control it from the inputs.

```
    //Case 1: Input control works
    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="value"/>
    <p-slider [(ngModel)]="value"></p-slider>
```

```
    //Case 2: Inputs controls don't work
    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="values[0]" />
    <p-slider [(ngModel)]="values" [range]="true"></p-slider>
    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="values[1]" />
```

If this doesn't work, how can I control a range slider from an input?"

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-slider-bug](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-slider-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar issue was reported and the solution suggested by [@Phil-DS on p-slider: when [range]='true', slider does not update when model changes](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12868#issuecomment-1503017765).

Angular doesn't mutate a value in the array to be updated.

You have to create the new array for each time the `<input>` element was inputted/changed in order to allow the update to be effected.

```
<input
    type="number"
    pInputText
    [(ngModel)]="values[0]"
    class="w-full mb-3"
    (input)="updateRange()"
  />

  <br />

  <p-slider [(ngModel)]="values" [range]="true" class="w-full"></p-slider>

  <input 
    type="number" 
    pInputText 
    [(ngModel)]="values[1]" 
    class="w-full mt-3" 
    (input)="updateRange()" />
```

```
updateRange() {
  this.values = [...this.values];
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-slider-bug-is4uad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)